# How to get REST request data using test case teardown script in soapUI

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

I am attempting to save all request and response data of every test step in my test case to that test cases custom properties. We are using soapUI 5.3.0 Open in CLI, and the testRunner report is set to export to a Junit report with test properties. We are trying this approach because the custom build monitoring system has issues looking at multiple files so we want everything in one massive ugly xml file (we aren't limiting ourselves to just the 5 properties listed below)

The code below handles alot better and does what i'm looking for. Havent tested via the CLI yet so i'll report back when i can (most likely tomorrow)

```
testRunner.results.each{ testStepResult -> testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("${testStepResult.testStep.name}_timeStamp","${testStepResult.timeStamp}")}
testRunner.results.each{ testStepResult -> testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("${testStepResult.testStep.name}_timeTaken","${testStepResult.timeTaken}")}
testRunner.results.each{ testStepResult -> testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("${testStepResult.testStep.name}_status","${testStepResult.status}")}
testRunner.results.each{ testStepResult ->
    def step = "${testStepResult.testStep.name}"
    try{response = new String(testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("$step").testRequest.messageExchange.rawResponseData)}catch(Exception e){e.getMessage()}
    try{request = new String(testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("$step").testRequest.messageExchange.rawRequestData)}catch(Exception e){e.getMessage()}
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("${testStepResult.testStep.name}_response",response)
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("${testStepResult.testStep.name}_request",request)
    request = ""
    response = ""
}
```

Comment: If the SOAPUI_HOME/bin/testrunner (.bat/.sh) command line utility is used to execute the tests, it automatically does what you are looking for, I believe and you do not have to worry about writing all that code.

Comment: Here is [dockerized soapui image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nmrao/soapui/) if want to give it a try quickly - allows to run projects in different ways including ant, which also can generate html reports on the mounted drive of your machine.

Comment: Thank you, I don't really want to go that approach. Its a bit complex to integrate with our current monitoring system (and the learning curve for those involved may not be a good thing at this stage) and will be done only as a last resort. I've updated my question slightly, and i'll get to this again later today. Thanks for the advice Rao :)

Comment: lol, so i got msgExchange to work changing t4 to`new String(testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("$step").testRequest.messageExchange.rawRequestData)` but now the script breaks if it's unable to find request data...like a property transfer and stuff...lol...getting there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way does work to grab both WSDL and REST request+response and confirmed working via the CLI

```
testRunner.results.each{ testStepResult -> testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("${testStepResult.testStep.name}_timeStamp","${testStepResult.timeStamp}")}
testRunner.results.each{ testStepResult -> testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("${testStepResult.testStep.name}_timeTaken","${testStepResult.timeTaken}")}
testRunner.results.each{ testStepResult -> testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("${testStepResult.testStep.name}_status","${testStepResult.status}")}
testRunner.results.each{ testStepResult ->
    def step = "${testStepResult.testStep.name}"
    try{response = new String(testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("$step").testRequest.messageExchange.rawResponseData)}catch(Exception e){e.getMessage()}
    try{request = new String(testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("$step").testRequest.messageExchange.rawRequestData)}catch(Exception e){e.getMessage()}
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("${testStepResult.testStep.name}_response",response)
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("${testStepResult.testStep.name}_request",request)
    request = ""
    response = ""
}
```

As you can see i had to wrap up the reqests\responses into a try\catch because not everything is REST or WSDL in a testcase.